# Back in the days vs back in the day

Tags: meaning, grammar, differences, british-english, sentence

I know that 'back in the day' can be used as a four-word temporal modifier:

- *Back in the day, we all used to meet down at the gym.*

Whereas 'back in the days' is not used on its own and always has a qualifier (e.g. "when ...", "before ..."):

- *Back in the days when a loaf of bread was only a nickel / two shillings, you could...*.

But I do hear some people say 'back in the days' *without* a qualifier.  Does this really matter in casual spoken English?

Comment: I’m confused. What are you  exactly  asking for?

Comment: My question is I hear so many people say 'back in the days' without a qualifier. Is it OK to  sometimes to say it without a qualifier because so many people make that mistake. Can you use both?

Comment: Just because many people make that Mistake doesn’t mean you have to too.

Comment: The original phrase is _back in the old days_, and it was plural. A more recent version is _back in the day_. So you can make that plural if you want; this is colloquial usage. If you're concerned about what's correct, listen to what the English speakers around you are saying and imitate them.

Comment: "back in the days when wishes were horses and beggar rode", is idiomatic. back in the day is used colloquially all the time these days and very often refers to a period that is not so far back....back in the days with an s will always be further qualified....